# How does priority interact with read_ahead in delayed_job?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

When delayed_job pulls a new job off the queue, does it sort the queue by priority first? If not, then I'm guessing low priority jobs can be run before high priority because of "read_ahead".

From the delayed_job documentation:

> The default behavior is to read 5 jobs from the queue when finding an
>   available job. You can configure this by setting
>   Delayed::Worker.read_ahead.

Example: I add 100 jobs with priority 10 (lower priorities are run first). I then add 1 job with priority 0. If I'm using the default read_ahead of 5, will delayed_job need to first process 96 jobs before finding one of my high priority jobs?

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar question and dug into the source code to find the answer - this is assuming you're using `delayed_job_active_record`.  In backend/active_record.rb:

```
  class Job < ::ActiveRecord::Base
    scope :by_priority, lambda { order("priority ASC, run_at ASC") }

    def self.reserve(worker, max_run_time = Worker.max_run_time) # rubocop:disable CyclomaticComplexity
      # scope to filter to records that are "ready to run"
      ready_scope = ready_to_run(worker.name, max_run_time)

      # scope to filter to the single next eligible job
      ready_scope = ready_scope.where("priority >= ?", Worker.min_priority) if Worker.min_priority
      ready_scope = ready_scope.where("priority <= ?", Worker.max_priority) if Worker.max_priority
      ready_scope = ready_scope.where(queue: Worker.queues) if Worker.queues.any?
      ready_scope = ready_scope.by_priority

      reserve_with_scope(ready_scope, worker, db_time_now)
    end

    def self.reserve_with_scope(ready_scope, worker, now)
      # Optimizations for faster lookups on some common databases
      case connection.adapter_name
      when "PostgreSQL"
        quoted_table_name = connection.quote_table_name(table_name)
        subquery_sql      = ready_scope.limit(1).lock(true).select("id").to_sql
        reserved          = find_by_sql(["UPDATE #{quoted_table_name} SET locked_at = ?, locked_by = ? WHERE id IN (#{subquery_sql}) RETURNING *", now, worker.name])
        reserved[0]
      when "MySQL", "Mysql2"
        now = now.change(usec: 0)
        count = ready_scope.limit(1).update_all(locked_at: now, locked_by: worker.name)
        return nil if count == 0
        where(locked_at: now, locked_by: worker.name, failed_at: nil).first
      when "MSSQL", "Teradata"
        subsubquery_sql = ready_scope.limit(1).to_sql
        subquery_sql = "SELECT id FROM (#{subsubquery_sql}) AS x"
        quoted_table_name = connection.quote_table_name(table_name)
        sql = ["UPDATE #{quoted_table_name} SET locked_at = ?, locked_by = ? WHERE id IN (#{subquery_sql})", now, worker.name]
        count = connection.execute(sanitize_sql(sql))
        return nil if count == 0
        where(locked_at: now, locked_by: worker.name, failed_at: nil).first
      else
        reserve_with_scope_using_default_sql(ready_scope, worker, now)
      end
    end

    def self.reserve_with_scope_using_default_sql(ready_scope, worker, now)
      # This is our old fashion, tried and true, but slower lookup
      ready_scope.limit(worker.read_ahead).detect do |job|
        count = ready_scope.where(id: job.id).update_all(locked_at: now, locked_by: worker.name)
        count == 1 && job.reload
      end
    end
```

So it looks like priority takes precedence - when DelayedJob is finding the next available job to reserve and run, it ranks by priority first before trying to limit the results by "read_ahead".

In fact, the last method `reserve_with_scope_using_default_sql` is the only place where "read_ahead" is even mentioned, so if you're using Postgres or MySQL it's automatically just choosing the highest-priority job (limit 1) and ignoring "read_ahead".